# create or derive package-lock.json file from npm-shrinkwrap.json

Tags: npm, npm-shrinkwrap, package-lock.json

Previously we had old version of npm and I used `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file to lock down the dependencies. Now we upgarded to npm 6 and I want to use `package-lock.json` instead of old `npm-shrinkwrap.json`  .

So how can I create a `package-lock.json` now?

- Is there any tool available for converting npm-shrinkwrap.json to
  package-lock.json?
- I've found the a [thread](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/672)
  which is suggesting to rename `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to
  `package-lock.json`.
- Is it okay to do that? because I'm not sure
  about the underlying logic for `npm shrinkwrap` and new `npm install`